# How can I print message in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I want to print some message while doing build process with a `makefile`. The following one can print the message, but it will not execute the script after it.  How can I fix this issues?

```
ifeq (yes, ${TEST})
        CXXFLAGS := ${CXXFLAGS} -DDESKTOP_TEST
test:
        @echo '************  TEST VERSION ************'
else
release:
        @echo "************ RELEASE VERSIOIN **********"
endif
```

Comment: "The script after it"? What script?

Comment: @Beta he means probably that the script doesn't continue after the line.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

It's not clear what you want, or whether you want this trick to work with different targets, or whether you've defined these targets elsewhere, or what version of Make you're using, but what the heck, I'll go out on a limb:

```
ifeq (yes, ${TEST})
CXXFLAGS := ${CXXFLAGS} -DDESKTOP_TEST
test:
$(info ************  TEST VERSION ************)
else
release:
$(info ************ RELEASE VERSIOIN **********)
endif
```

Answer (score 133):

> `$(info your_text)`    : **Information**. This doesn't stop the execution.
>
> `$(warning your_text)` : **Warning**. This shows the text as a warning.
>
> `$(error your_text)`   : **Fatal Error**. This will stop the execution.

See [*GNU make: 8.13 Functions That Control Make*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Make-Control-Functions) for details.

Comment: how to print variable in Makefile？

Comment: @CSQGB If you are asking for shell variables, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47367937/2932052