# Printing in Makefiles: @echo vs $(info )

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

What is the difference between these two commands in makefiles:

```
@echo "Hello World"
$(info Hello World)
```

As it seems, `echo` and `info` print the same output, so where is the difference? 
And when to use which one?

Comment: If you have both in your receipt, echo comes last.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, `echo` is a shell command.  So if you put it in a recipe, a shell will be invoked to run it and the shell command will generate the output:

```
foo: ; @echo "Hello World"
```

runs `/bin/sh -c 'echo "Hello World"'`.  It can only be used in a recipe.  It will work in any version of make, and with any POSIX shell.  Because it invokes a shell, you may need to be concerned with quoting issues, etc. (not in this simple example of course).

`info` is a GNU make function.  It is handled directly by make: no shell is invoked.  It can appear anywhere in a makefile, not just in a recipe.  It is not portable to other versions of make.  Because no shell is invoked, there are no quoting issues.

However, because `info` is a make function it is parsed by make before the shell is invoked: that means it can't show shell variables that are set within a recipe; for example:

```
foo: ; @for i in a b c d; do $(info $$i); done
```

cannot work; you must use `echo` here.

Comment: I think it's also executed in different order `@echo ...\n$(info ...)\n`  will print info first. (The `\n` is meant literally here)

Comment: Yes, this is part of what I meant by "it is parsed by make before the shell is invoked".  I should have said "expanded" here not "parsed" since "expanded" is the term used by make.